# CKEditor - Fix drop down positions or replace with prompt box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

I am having issues with the drop down menus of CKEditor (version 4.5.11). I have applied a style to the CKEditor tool bar to have it fixed to the top of the page. Now I am experiencing problems with the drop down menus (style, font, size...). When I scroll down the page they pop to the bottom of the page, away from the drop down button.

I was wondering if I could change the way these options are called. It would be good if I could just call them into the prompt box used for other options; The way the image prompt box works for example.

I will post images of what I have going on and a link to download an example. (This will be hosted on my Google drive)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to example files:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B918caL_HYSUUERlSG03THRrUGM/view?usp=sharing

[Example of CKEditor misbehaving - IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuust.png)

Hint: Scroll down to allow CKEditor to pop to the top, click to drop down a menu. Then with that menu open, scroll the page. - The issue will occur.

Note: I have removed the glyphicons from the example due to licensing. If you find any other code in the example useful your free to keep it and use it.